# invalid literal for int() with base 10 '0|0' error?

Tags: python

I am getting the error:  invalid literal for int() with base 10 '0|0'. I am not sure if the problem is the format 0|0 instead of 0:0 since it looks like it is splitting the field by ":", or if it's something related to self.depthpos. The traceback says:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "vcftopf_p1_commandline.py", line 200, in <module>
snps[i]=snp(lin)
  File "vcftopf_p1_commandline.py", line 140, in __init__
if int(gtype[self.depthpos])>=cutoff:                                   
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '0|0'
```

Piece of code looks like:

```
self.info=lsp[7]
    isplit=self.info.split(';')
    infonum=0
    for infofield in isplit:
        if infofield.split('=')[0]=='AA':
            self.ancestinfo=True
            self.ancest=infofield.split('=')[1]
            if self.ancest=='.':
                self.failed=1
                return
        infonum+=1 
    self.format=lsp[8]
    self.gtypes=lsp[9:]


fsp=self.format.split(':')
    self.fdpos=-1
    self.depthpos=-1
    formatnum=0
    for field in fsp:
        if field=='DP':
            self.depthpos=formatnum
        formatnum+=1       
    #if (len(self.gtypes)!=nsamp):
    #   raise(" incorrect number of individuals in line "+line)


            i=0
            for fd in fsp:

                if fd=="FD":
                        self.fdpos=i
                i=i+1


    if self.fdpos!=-1:
                for gtypestr in self.gtypes:
            gtype=gtypestr.split(':') 

            if gtype[self.fdpos]=='0':              
                            self.nalt+=int( gtype[0][0]=='1')+int( gtype[0][2]=='1')
                            self.nref+=int( gtype[0][0]=='0')+int( gtype[0][2]=='0')
                    #print self.nref,self.nalt



        else:
            for gtypestr in self.gtypes:
            gtype=gtypestr.split(':')   
                        #print gtype
                        if gtype[0]!='.' and gtype[0]!='./.':
                if int(gtype[self.depthpos])>=cutoff:                                    
                    self.nalt+=int( gtype[0][0]=='1')+int( gtype[0][2]=='1')
                        self.nref+=int( gtype[0][0]=='0')+int( gtype[0][2]=='0')
                #print self.nref,self.nalt
```

Input looks like:

```
#CHROM  POS     ID      REF     ALT     QUAL    FILTER  INFO    FORMAT  HG01112 HG01113 HG01119 
1       14674   .       G       A       100     PASS    .       GT      0|0     0|0     0|0
```

Comment: Please provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Did you try replacing `gtype=gtypestr.split(':')` by `gtype=gtypestr.split('|')`?

Comment: I did but then got an error saying string index out of bounds

Comment: Your code is tough to follow, it's unclear what you're trying to accomplish. But `int()` requires a string that contains *nothing* except the digits you're trying to turn into a single integer. The string you're passing has two numbers with a `|` in the middle.

Comment: Please fix the indentation of your code.

Comment: What is the problem you are trying to solve with this code?  Are you trying to do a line-by-line process on a source file?  Also, what does 0|0 indicate?  Is that a floating point number, or an integer, or a ratio?

Comment: The problem is this is someone else's code I am supposed to use on my files, and I don't know python. I am trying to figure it out. I realized I am not supposed to be splitting the 0|0 field, just accessing the first and third elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several problems happening here.  First is that the formatting on your code makes it hard to read for people who have spent a lot of time programming in particular Python style standards.  I'd recommend you start with [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) and evolve your style from there.

I *think* this code reformat retains the meaning of your code.  Please correct me if I am wrong.

```
self.info = lsp[7]
isplit = self.info.split(';')
infonum = 0
for infofield in isplit:
    if infofield.split('=')[0] == 'AA':
        self.ancestinfo = True
        self.ancest = infofield.split('=')[1]
        if self.ancest == '.':
            self.failed = 1
            return
        infonum += 1 
self.format = lsp[8]
self.gtypes = lsp[9:]
     
fsp = self.format.split(':')
self.fdpos = -1
self.depthpos = -1
formatnum = 0
for field in fsp:
    if field == 'DP':
        self.depthpos = formatnum
    formatnum += 1       
    #if len(self.gtypes) != nsamp:
    #    raise(" incorrect number of individuals in line " + line)

i = 0
for fd in fsp:
    if fd == "FD":
        self.fdpos = i
        i = i + 1
     
if self.fdpos != -1:
    for gtypestr in self.gtypes:
        gtype = gtypestr.split(':') 
        if gtype[self.fdpos] == '0':
            self.nalt += int(gtype[0][0] == '1') + int(gtype[0][2] == '1')
            self.nref += int(gtype[0][0] == '0') + int(gtype[0][2] == '0')
            #print self.nref,self.nalt

else:
    for gtypestr in self.gtypes:
        gtype = gtypestr.split(':')   
        #print gtype
        if gtype[0] != '.' and gtype[0] != './.':
            if int(gtype[self.depthpos]) >= cutoff:                                    
                self.nalt += int(gtype[0][0] == '1') + int(gtype[0][2] == '1')
                self.nref += int(gtype[0][0] == '0') + int(gtype[0][2] == '0')
                #print self.nref,self.nalt
```

**First Problem**

The original problem you had was `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '0|0'` - this is because you have the following values when you call
`gtype = gtypestr.split(':')` with your sample input:

```
self.gtypes = ['0|0', '0|0', '0|0']
gtypestr = '0|0'
self.depthpos = -1
```

The output of a `str.split(delimiter)` is always a list, so `gtype` has the value `['0|0']`.

`gtype[self.depthpos]` is equal to `gtype[-1]`, which is equal to `gtype[0]` because `gtype` is a list of length 1.

Hence, you call `int('0|0')`, which gives you the error.

**Second Problem**

The suggestion that you change the `gtypestr.split(':')` to `gtypestr.split('|')` assumes that the error is from splitting on the wrong character.  That change gives you

```
gtype = ['0', '0']
int(gtype[self.depthpos]) == int(gtype[-1]) == int('0') == 0
```

`cutoff` isn't defined in the code sample you gave us, but I will assume that `0 >= cutoff` and we then run this block:

```
self.nalt += int(gtype[0][0] == '1') + int(gtype[0][2] == '1')
self.nref += int(gtype[0][0] == '0') + int(gtype[0][2] == '0')
```

This is what's giving you the `IndexError: string index out of range` when you call `gtype[0][2]` - that's equivalent to calling `'0'[2]`, and there's no THIRD character in a single character string.

This block looks like it's trying to work around a delimiter in the middle of the first substring that's returned by the `.split(':')` call.

So I'm not sure how to move forward:

- fix those `gtype[0]` substring calls to work against a different string?
- keep the `.split(':')` and change the cutoff test?
- both of these are symptoms of a complex input file format that needs to be simplified?

Can you tell us anything more about the input format?

Comment: Thank you. Your comments have clarified and I am now able to run the script. This is someone else's code (I don't know python) that I was instructed to use on my files. I have realized that I am not supposed to split 0|0, and am supposed to access the first and third elements of this field, ignoring "|". I am counting the numbers of 0's and 1's in this field, as the input can take the form of 0|0, 0|1, 1|0, 1|1. I believe gtype[self.depthpos] should be calling on a different string, as you stated.

Answer (score 0):

The exception means that the string `'0|0'` is an invalid value to pass to the `int()` function.  To fix this, make sure the string contains a valid [integer literal](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#integers).

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the eval call on the string

```
int(eval("0|0"))
```

result : 1

Answer (score -1):

`int()` takes integers, you are trying to give a decimal, so you need to use `float()`

**Your Code:**

```
if int(gtype[self.depthpos])>=cutoff:
```

**Change and try this:**

```
if float(gtype[self.depthpos])>=cutoff:
```

Comment: then I get invalid literal for float(): 0|0

Comment: You try replace: `gtype=gtypestr.split(':')` to `gtype=gtypestr.split('|')`

Comment: That's because `gtype[0][2]` is trying to get the THIRD element of a string of length 1.